# What are some good resources for setting up and debugging neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, reference-request

I am aware of [Troubleshooting Deep Neural Networks](http://josh-tobin.com/troubleshooting-deep-neural-networks.html) by Josh Tobin and [A Recipe for Training Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/) by Andrej Karpathy, but I am interested in other resources that can give me some guidelines or steps to setting up and debugging neural networks.